# Trouble with operator overloading and inferred types in Swift

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, operators, type-inference, literals

### Literals

Swift has a couple of *literals* that can be used to initialize different types without explicitly calling their initializer. For example,

```
let x = 5             // x is now an Int
```

automatically infers `x` to be of type `Int`. But if we specify the type of the variable to be something else

```
let x: UInt = 5       // x is now a UInt
```

the compiler automatically understands that `5` is now an unsigned integer and so the respective `UInt` initializer has to be called instead of the `Int` initializer.

---

### The `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol

This is possible for all types that implement the protocol `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. Now I add this protocol conformance to my own type:

```
/// Represents a range of characters in a `String`.
//
/// The only purpose of this type is to provide a wrapper around `CountableClosedRange`
/// that can be initialized both with a range and an **integer literal**.
struct TextRange: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {

    let range: CountableClosedRange<Int>

    var lowerBound: Int {
        return range.lowerBound
    }

    var upperBound: Int {
        return range.upperBound
    }

    init(_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) {
        self.range = range
    }

    // This initializer adds the protocol conformance:
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.range = value...value
    }

}
```

With this definition I can write:

```
let x: TextRange = 5    // x is now a `TextRange`
```

However,

```
let x = 5               // x is now an `Int`
```

still infers x to be an `Int`. So far, so good.

---

### Overloading the `...` operator

Now I also want to be able to create a `TextRange` with the closed range operator `...` like this:

```
let y: TextRange = 5...10
```

so I overload the `...` operator in an extension for `TextRange`s:

```
extension TextRange {

    /// Given two text ranges, this operator creates a new text range that incorporates
    /// the integers within the operand ranges as well as all integers between the operand ranges.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lowerRange: A text range whose lower bound is smaller than the lower bound of `upperRange`.
    ///   - upperRange: A text range whose lower bound is greater than the lower bound of `lowerRange`.
    /// - Returns: A `TextRange` from the first operand's lower bound to the second operand's upper bound.
    static func ...(lowerRange: TextRange, upperRange: TextRange) -> TextRange {

        let lowerBound = lowerRange.lowerBound
        let upperBound = max(lowerRange.upperBound, upperRange.upperBound)

        assert(lowerBound <= upperBound, "Cannot create a TextRange because lowerBound > upperBound.")

        return TextRange(lowerBound...upperBound)
    }

}
```

And this is where I get into trouble. *(What a surprise: The trouble begins with operator overloading!* *)*

---

### Trouble

For a variable of `TextRange` type this operator works as expected but when I omit the type annotation the variable is still instantiated as a `TextRange`:

```
let y = 5...10           // y is now a `TextRange`
```

**That shouldn't be** because:

- If no type is specified for a variable,

  > the default inferred type of an integer literal is the Swift standard library type Int.

  (see [*Integer Literals* in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html))

  Thus, I would expect `5` and `10` to be inferred to `Int`, not `TextRange`.
- The overload of the `...` operator is only implemented for two operands of `TextRange` type. Thus, `x...y` should still use the original Swift implementation of `...` if `x` and `y` are both `Int`s.

So why does the compiler "decide" that it should now use the overloaded operator by default for ranges between two integer literals and interpret `x` and `y` in the pattern `x...y` as `TextRange`s?

#### Is there a way to tell the compiler which operator should be used by default in case the type of the two operands is not specified?

Comment: My guess: You have defined a non-generic `...` operator, and that takes precedence over the existing generic versions. – You probably meant `let y = 5...10`

Comment: Well, I found that `(1 as Int)...(5 as Int)` works, but its ugly :(

Comment: @MartinR: Sounds reasonable. So the compiler first tries to resolve the `...` operator expression. It searches for all implementations of that operator whose operands are `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. If there is still ambiguity (i.e more than one implementation matching this pattern) it chooses the non-generic over the generic implementation where it _should_ (in my opinion) choose "the default type of an integer literal" `Int`. Fixed the typo, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Sweeper: Yes, the problem only occurs when the type of the integer literal is _inferred_ (i.e. not explicitly specified).